# Reset license key for MS Mac Office 2011

Tags: ms-office

I need to enter a new MS Office for Mac license key.
How can I reset my old one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this forum post](http://www.officeformac.com/ms/.59bc206d/0):

> Ditch `/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.licensing.plist`. Start any Office application. Reregister/reactivate.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To add to this, once you delete /Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.licensing.plist you then need to reboot.  The activate office screen will then come up when you open any Office app.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work if you switch computers, Office will complain that product has been used the maximum number of times.

One has to call them to reset activations.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can add a comment on the answer you wanted to comment on. Alternatively, you can offer a new answer instead that you feel is a better solution. See [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.